# SQL- Select items that have been on hand for > 1 year without sale.

Tags: sql

Looking for a quick code in order to keep my inventory fresh. I'm looking to select all items that are currently in stock at a location, when they were last received and their last sale date.

The desired result will bring a list of all items in stock at a store location that has been received a year ago or more and has not sold during that time.  Ideally, the last received and last sold will be MAX or TOP value so that I don't have excess clutter stating each time it was sold or received in the past year.

Notes:

To_Location = Last time inventory was delivered to the store.

LocationID = All items currently in stock in a store.

Current Code:

```
`SELECT LocationID, To_Location, Received_Date, Item, Description, Last_Sold, Quantity_Available

FROM Generictable

WHERE  LocationID = 'STORE1' AND QTY_AVAIL > 0 AND To_Location = 'Store1') 
AND  Received_Date <= DATEADD(month, - 12, GETDATE())) 
AND Last_Sold <= DATEADD(month, - 12, GETDATE()))

 OR

LocationID = 'Store1' AND Quantity_Available > 0
 AND To_Location = 'Store1'
 AND Last_Received <= DATEADD(month, - 12, GETDATE()))
AND Last_Sold IS NULL) OR (Last_Sold = '')`
```

I know that I should be using SELECT MAX somewhere here, but each time I try in a subquery it keeps recalling duplicates. Maybe due to an improper join?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That query is using product specific functions.

Comment: It also doesn't appear to be valid SQL in any variant due to the excess of closing parentheses?

Comment: Tip of today: count `(` and `)`. Should always be the same number of them.

Comment: it's looks like TSQL and that **OR** don't seems quite right. All you need is to check for Received_Date <= DATEADD(month, - 12, GETDATE())  and (Last_Sold IS NULL OR Last_Sold <= DATEADD(month, - 12, GETDATE()) )

Comment: Provide sample data and desires results.